# How to insert a backslash and a newline before a pattern?

Tags: text-processing

i wanted to capture \n in a variable (assume a) and substitute $a in front of search pattern in a file (abc.txt)

can somebody suggest me the solution ?

```
> cat abc.txt
hi how are you how is your health
> echo $a
\
```

expected output  ( search pattern - `how`)

```
hi \
how are you \
how is your health
```

Comment: a=$(printf "\n") ?

Comment: @RamanSailopal, that wouldn't work as command substitution strips trailing newline characters.

Comment: What does "in front of a search pattern in a file" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Bourne-like or rc-like shell

```
a='
' perl -pe 's/pattern/$ENV{a}$&/g' < abc.txt
```

would pass a `a` environment variable to `perl` containing a newline character and `perl` would insert the  content of that variable before each occurrence of `pattern` in the content of `abc.txt`.

To assign any character `x` other than `'` to a variable in Bourne-like shells, you can use:

```
a='x'
```

So for backslash:

```
a='\'
```

For newline:

```
a='
'
```

For control characters like newline, but that would be even worse for backspace or carriage-return for instance, however, that renders the code less legible.

ksh93 introduced a new `$'...'` form of quotes to specify those characters in an escaped form. Other shells like `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh` or FreeBSD `sh` have copied and extended (like the `$'\uXXXX'` form added by `zsh`) it since.

In those shells, you can use:

```
a=$'\n' a=$'\b' a=$'\r' a=$'\\' a=$'\''
```

To assign a newline, backspace, carriage return, backslash or single quote character.

That quoting operator is not standard yet, so you can't use it in a portable `sh` script. A standard alternative is to use:

```
a=$(printf '\b')
```

for backspace for instance, but that doesn't work for newline as command substitution (`$(cmd)`) strips trailing newline characters from the output of `cmd`. One has to resort to hacks like:

```
nl=$(printf '\n.'); nl=${nl%.}
```

(that is add a `.` and remove it afterwards) in order to preserve it.

Note that `perl` also understands those `\n` notations in its code, so you can do:

```
perl -pe 's/pattern/\n$&/g' < abc.txt
```

The GNU implementation of `sed` (and a few others nowadays) also support it:

```
sed 's/pattern/\n&/g' < abc.txt
```

but that's not standard. Standardly, a newline in the replacement part of the `s` command in `sed` has to be expressed with a backslash followed by an actually newline, so that would be:

```
backslash='\' newline='
'
sed "s/pattern/$backslash$newline&/g" < abc.txt
```

Or without the variables:

```
sed 's/pattern/\
&/g' < abc.txt
```

So, if you want to insert both a backslash and a newline in front of `pattern`, you need:

```
sed 's/pattern/\\\
&/g' < abc.txt
```

3 backslashes in total, two for a literal backslash and one for the newline. Or with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/pattern/\\\n$&/g' < abc.txt
```

Or with your `a` variable:

```
a='\
' perl -pe 's/pattern/$ENV{a}$&/g' < abc.txt
```

Comment: =======
> echo $a
\
> a='
' perl -pe 's/how/$ENV{a}$&/g' < abc.txt
hi
how are you
===========

@StéphaneChazelas .. this is not printing \ (backslash)

Comment: @Vika, see edit. I see that you've now clarified your question.

Comment: it worked .. thank you 
==============
> sed 's/how/\\\
> &/g' < abc.txt
hi \
how are you \
how is your health
============
when I use sed -i (to edit the same file ) it is complaining "sed: no input files". can you help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the own bash commands using:

```
cat abc.txt | sed -e 's/how/\nhow/g' |  while read line; do echo "$line \\"; done
```

Comment: this is printing \ at the end of all lines.